# Application not launching after hiding it from app drawer on android

Tags: android, hide, launch

I have an application and I start it **remotely** with a `broadcast receiver`.
I used this method to hide it from app drawer:

```
public static void hideFromAppDrawer(Context c) {
        ComponentName componentToDisable = new ComponentName(
                "mypackage", "mypackage.MyMainActivity");

        c.getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(componentToDisable,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    }
```

But after hiding, (i hided the laucher activity, and after that i want to launch the same activity remotely) the application does not start. The log says:

```
03-27 15:00:53.494: E/AndroidRuntime(23392): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-27 15:00:53.494: E/AndroidRuntime(23392): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver mypackage.receivers.myReceiver: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {mypackage/mypackage.MyMainActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
03-27 15:00:53.494: E/AndroidRuntime(23392):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2383)
```

The error is in the `broadcast receiver's` `onReceive()` method when I am trying to start the activity:

```
context.startActivity(i);

03-27 15:00:53.494: E/AndroidRuntime(23392):    at ... .onReceive(MyReceiver.java:36)
```

What could be the problem and how can I launch my application while it is hidden from the app drawer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What could be the problem

You disabled the component, which means it cannot be started.

> how can I launch my application while it is hidden from the app drawer?

You can try this:

- Set up an `<activity-alias>` manifest entry, pointing to your activity, that contains your `MAIN`/`LAUNCHER` `<intent-filter>` (removing that filter from the original `<activity>`)
- Disable the `<activity-alias>` using your above Java code, leaving the original activity intact
- Ensure that your `BroadcastReceiver` references the activity, as it should be already

In principle, this should work, though I have not tried this specific recipe.

Comment: simple and awesome! Thanks for the quick answer! First I got an error because I put the `alias-activity` before the real one, now fine.